# Should I split a Python class with many methods into multiple classes?

Tags: python, refactoring, class

I have a class that will end up having more than ~30 methods. They all make sense to be part of the same class because they require access to the same data.

However, does it make any sense to split up a large class into several smaller abstract classes (by functionality, type, use, etc.) and have the main class extend (i.e. multiple inheritance) from all the smaller classes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

If you create several different classes and inherit them all in a single class you've haven't really improved the situation. You've just one class which is pretending to be a whole bunch of classes. You've made the implementation a lot more complicated and you haven't actually separated the pieces at all. If A inherits from B and C, then A is as complicated as B and C.

Having more than 30 methods does suggest it could benefit from being split up. Maybe there is a clever way to split it up. Sometimes you just can't, and in that case I do recommend have a large class. But often there are clever ways to break the object into several objects.

Answer (score 0):

Just because things need data access doesn't means they belong in the same class. They belong in the same class if they share responsibility for protecting invariants, or are a naturally cohesive group of things that consumers will want to pass around wholesale.

A more likely scenario is that you have multiple classes that all contain the data (or data provider) passed in via constructor (or otherwise dependency inverted).